# turn image into string from <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, image, base64, html5-canvas

Is it possible to turn an image into a base64 string with these restrictions,

1. Image is coming from `<input type="file"/>`
2. No internet connection
3. Mobile Browser

I know I can download an image and convert it using `<canvas>`, but is it possible to access the image before it's uploaded? If this is not possible I am going to write a PhoneGap plugin.

Thanks!

Edit-

Got this working using the FileReader API. Here's the relivant code,

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(theFile) {
    var base64Image = theFile.srcElement.result;
};

// Read in the image file as a data URL.
reader.readAsDataURL(image.fileElement.dom.files[0]);
```

Comment: Have a look at the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) and [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) APIs.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks for this, I think I was looking for readAsDataURL().

Comment: Yep!  `readAsDataURL` will give you a base64 version of your image.  Note it will return a string like `data:image/png;base64,<data>`, so you're gonna have to parse out the base64 data from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intercept the `submit` event on the form, and read the data there. You can abort submission if you want, and just keep the data locally.